# How to get retry count from ActiveMQ Artemis message

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-artemis

I'm taking the message from an ActiveMQ Artemis queue and trying to send it to an invalid HTTP endpoint (through a Camel route) it fails and the message gets retried. Whenever message delivery fails it gets retried at ActiveMQ Artemis level. Retry configuration is available in broker. Is there any way to get current retry count for a JMS message in client applications?

I can maintain retry count in DB per message - looking for better solution / existing methods etc.

If I try to maintain the count and set it in the message header then during retry those get lost. Retry happens as if it's a new message. So can't use it.

We are using `org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent` with the Qpid JMS client.

Comment: Any feedback here? Did you get this sorted?

Comment: looks like Apache camel removing and adding it's own headers CamelRedeliveryCounter & CamelRedelivered. The problem is even tho camel using its own headers it's not maintaining what Artemis maintains. So i always get  CamelRedeliveryCounter = 0 and CamelRedelivered as false.

Comment: So it appears that ActiveMQ Artemis and the Qpid JMS client are doing what they should so the issue is with Camel. Perhaps you should ask a new question specifically dealing with Camel.

Answer (score 0):

You should **inspect** the `JMSXDeliveryCount` property on the message. Section 3.5.9 of the JMS 1.1 specification says this about `JMSXDeliveryCount`:

> The number of message delivery attempts; the first is 1, the second 2,...

I just tested this with Qpid JMS 1.7.0 and ActiveMQ Artemis 2.27.1 and it worked fine in both transacted and non-transacted use-cases. In both cases the `JMSRedelivered` header and the `JMSXDeliveryCount` property were set appropriately.

Here's the code for the transacted use-case:

```java
try (Connection connection = new JmsConnectionFactory("amqp://127.0.0.1:5672").createConnection()) {
   Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
   Queue queue = session.createQueue("myQueue");
   MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
   MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
   TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("test-message");
   producer.send(message);
   session.commit();
   producer.close();
   connection.start();
   message = (TextMessage) consumer.receive(1000);
   System.out.println("Redelivered? " + message.getJMSRedelivered());
   System.out.println("Delivery count: " + message.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount"));
   message.acknowledge();
   session.rollback();
   message = (TextMessage) consumer.receive(1000);
   System.out.println("Redelivered? " + message.getJMSRedelivered());
   System.out.println("Delivery count: " + message.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount"));
}
```

Here's the code for the non-transacted use-case:

```java
try (Connection connection = new JmsConnectionFactory("amqp://127.0.0.1:5672").createConnection()) {
   Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
   Queue queue = session.createQueue("myQueue");
   MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
   MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
   TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("test-message");
   producer.send(message);
   producer.close();
   connection.start();
   message = (TextMessage) consumer.receive(1000);
   System.out.println("Redelivered? " + message.getJMSRedelivered());
   System.out.println("Delivery count: " + message.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount"));
   session.close();
   session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
   consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
   message = (TextMessage) consumer.receive(1000);
   System.out.println("Redelivered? " + message.getJMSRedelivered());
   System.out.println("Delivery count: " + message.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount"));
}
```

In both cases this is what was printed:

```
Redelivered? false
Delivery count: 1
Redelivered? true
Delivery count: 2
```

The behavior you're seeing with the message being redelivered as "a new message" is expected. As noted in section 3.10 of the JMS 1.1 specification:

> A consumer can modify a received message after calling either the *clearBody* or *clearProperties* method to make the body or properties writable. If the consumer modifies a received message, and the message is subsequently redelivered, the redelivered message must be the original, unmodified message (except for headers and properties modified by the JMS provider as a result of the redelivery, such as the *JMSRedelivered* header and the *JMSXDeliveryCount* property).

I'm not a Camel expert so I can't say exactly is Camel doing with the JMS message when delivery to the HTTP endpoint fails. All I know is that this works fine with straight JMS. I would expect this to work with Camel also, but Camel may be doing their own form of retry rather than using the redelivery which JMS provides.

This would be relatively trivial to validate by [turning on AMQP frame tracing from the Qpid JMS client](https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-2.1.0/docs/index.html#logging) and inspecting the frames around message delivery and the resulting disposition.

Comment: No Sir, even if I only print.. these are null. I don't think ActiveMQ / Artemis even maintains it. I also don't see it in Artemis console through browsing queues.

Comment: I'm taking the message from Artemis queue, and try to send it to an invalid HTTP endpoint (through the camel route) it fails and the message gets retried. In your broker does persist-delivery-count-before-delivery set to true ?

Comment: I'm using the default value for `persist-delivery-count-before-delivery` which is `false`. In any event, that setting is only relevant for situations where the broker is stopped or crashes while messages are being redelivered.

Comment: This would be relatively trivial to validate by turning on AMQP frame tracing from the QPId JMS client and inspecting the frames around message delivery and the resulting disposition.  My guess is Camel is consuming the message and redelivering it itself.

Comment: @TimBish I'm also thinking the same because camel does have similar fields.